# StreamWriter truncating text while writing to a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a huge content in a string variable and I want to write that content to a text file using stream writer. But the stream writer is truncating the text and not writing the whole content to file. Why?

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(completeFilePath))
{
    sw.Write(txt);
}
```

Comment: where's the code where you assign to `html`? And is it always truncating to the same maximum length?

Comment: Are you checking before the end of the using statement? Because the using statement implicitly calls Dispose() when it falls out of scope, which calls Flush() automatically.

Answer (score 8):

After Write, use Flush method to clear buffer.

```
sw.Write(Html);
sw.Flush();
```

Comment: this fixed my issue. I was trying to achieve a similar task. In some cases the html being written was truncated other cases nothing was written at all. Makes me wonder what `Flush()` is actually doing to fix the problem.

Comment: @Adeel That was my issue, the buffer is about 2 or 4kb so it can actually hold the whole text file in memory and never write it out. I was pulling out my hair trying to figure out what the difference in the strings were.

Answer (score 1):

If the size is too large,

```
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(completeFilePath))
{
    sw.Write(txt);
    //just to make sure the stream writer flushes the command
    sw.Flush();
}
```

If the size isn't that large, I suggest to use File.WriteAllText method

```
//no need to Open or Close anything
File.WriteAllText(Path, txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `txt` is a string variable containing the HTML, try calling [`sw.Flush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx) after `sw.Write()`. That should force the stream writer to write the rest of the string to the file. If the file is still truncated, ensure `txt` string contains the full output as intended.

Comment: Isn't stream flushing in Dispose?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It should but this will categorically exclude the stream from the problem in the absence of any other code, such as that to create Html.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
File.WriteAllText(completeFilePath, txt);
```

[MSDN Documentation for File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx)